# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel_abonamenty2.currencies' doesn't exist

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, frameworks

I've got this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel_abonamenty2.currencies' doesn't exist (SQL: select `id`, `currency`, `course` from `currencies`)
```

This is my controller which generate error. I don't know why Laravel is searching for currencies table. My table and migration is called Currencys.

```
public function create()
{
    $users = User::all('showname', 'id');
    $forms = Form::all('id', 'form');
    $currencys = Currency::all('id', 'currency', 'course');
    return view('invoices.create')->with('users', $users, 'forms', 'currencys');
}
```

This is mine currency model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Currency extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'currency', 'course',
    ];

    public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
    }

    public function proform()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Proform');
    }
}
```

This is my Currencys migration

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Currencys extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('currencys', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('currency')->nullable();
            $table->string('course')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('currencys');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the plural of `currency` is **currencies** and not **currencys**. Laravel automatically detects the table name of the `snake case plural` name of the model. [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

In your model you can specify another table name like:

```
protected $table = 'currencys';
```

With that laravel will search the currencys table.

Comment: such a bad design decision in laravel, leading to unpredictable errors.

Answer (score 1):

> By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used
> as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified.
> https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

In your case, it converts the `Currency`(model name) to plural `currencies`. Therefore,if you want a custom table name,

You need to specify that name of the table in the model.

Currency Model

```
class Currency extends Model
{
  protected $table="currency";
...
}
```